# How to reliably overwrite a file in Windows

Tags: windows, file-io, corruption

I want to overwrite the content of a file atomically. I need this to maintain integrity when overwriting a config file, so an update should either pass or fail and never leave the file half-written or corrupted.

I went through multiple iteration to solve this problem, here is my current solution.

Steps to overwrite file "foo.config":

- Enter a global mutex (unique per file name)
- Write the new content in "foo.config.tmp"
- Call [FlushFileBuffers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364439(v=vs.85).aspx) on the file handle before closing the file to flush the OS file buffers
- Call [ReplaceFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365512(v=vs.85).aspx) which will internally

  - rename "foo.config" to "foo.config.bak"
  - rename "foo.config.tmp" to "foo.config"
- Delete "foo.config.bak"
- Release the global mutex

I thought this solution to be robust, but the dreaded issue occurred again in production after a power failure. The config file was found corrupted, filled with 'NULL' character, .tmp or .bak file did not exist.

My theory is that the original file content was zeroed out when deleting "foo.config.bak" but the filesystem metadata update caused by the ReplaceFile call was not flushed to disk. So after reboot, "foo.config" is pointing to the original file content that has been zeroed out, is that even possible since ReplaceFile is called before DeleteFile?

The file was stored on an SSD (SanDisk X110).

Do you see a flaw in my file overwrite procedure? Could it be an hardware failure in the SSD? Do you have an idea to guarantee the atomicity of the file overwrite even in case of power failure? Ideally I'd like to delete the tmp and bak file after the overwrite.

Thanks,

Comment: Deleting a file does not zero the content.  I think it more likely that the data written to foo.config.tmp never reached the disk, perhaps because of caching inside the SSD, or the file system itself may have become corrupt and the data was lost during the self-repair.  There really isn't any robust way to prevent a power cut from causing this sort of problem, though turning off write caching (via Device Manager) may help.  Other suggestions are battery-backed disk and/or UPS for the server.

Comment: Your ReplaceFile approach seems sound, but there's all sorts of code between you and the disc (or SSD) that may not do what you expect in the face of a power outage.  (I've known at least one hard drive that would happily tell the OS that all its caches had been flushed when actually they hadn't.)  I highly recommend an uninterruptable power supply.

Answer (score 0):

Use [MoveFileEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240(v=vs.85).aspx) with the `MOVEFILE_WRITE_THROUGH` flag when renaming the file. This should tell windows to write the file right away, not caching it.

Comment: But it's not just Windows.  When instructed to write-through, some drives will cheat and return a success code before the data is actually committed to persistent storage.